# Retreive data from Firebase from table where rows have specific values

Tags: java, android, json, firebase

I'm currently developing an android app using Android Studio and Firebase and I'm thinking how to build my database in the best JSON format which will be the optimal over time.

Its a service app, with `tbl_parent_categories`, `tbl_child_categories` and `tbl_services`.

Is it possible to execute a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_services WHERE child_category_name = 'technicians'
```

and if the answer is yes, how can I do it? I already implemented the code for connections etc, but how can I do that query?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, [here's](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data) the part of the docs that describes how you do it. You need to use a combination of `orderByChild` and `equalTo`. Something like this should work:

```
Query myQuery = databaseReference.child("tbl_services")
                                 .orderByChild("child_category_name")
                                 .equalTo("technicians");
```

Comment: Thats really nice! Thank you very much! Is it case sensitive or not?

Comment: the table names should probably be case sensitive, yes